# Dspace 6.x xmlui - modify the full item view

Tags: dspace

I'm using Dspace v 6.3 xmlui, and the default theme (Mirage2)
I want to modify the visualization of the complete registry of the items, so the dublin core fields are shown by the tags and not the complete name of the field. Is this possible?
Right now, a complete registry in my Dspace looks like this:
[image]

I know I have to modify the `item-view.xsl` file, but I have two doubts about it:

1. Most of the questions I've seen about this are refered to the summary view, but I want to modify the full view. I'm in the right file?
2. I don't know which part of the code is specifically for the tag.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In lines 501-509 of [`item-view.xsl`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L501-L509), replace it with the code below. Note that you have to add each label that you want to display in the detailed view. In the example code below, I only included author, title, and the abstract label.

```
<td class="label-cell">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@element='contributor' and @qualifier='author'">
            <i18n:text>xmlui.dri2xhtml.METS-1.0.item-author</i18n:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@element='title'">
            <i18n:text>xmlui.dri2xhtml.METS-1.0.item-title</i18n:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@element='description' and @qualifier='abstract'">
            <i18n:text>xmlui.dri2xhtml.METS-1.0.item-abstract</i18n:text>
        </xsl:when>
<!-- More to be added here -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@mdschema"/>
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@element"/>
            <xsl:if test="./@qualifier">
                <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./@qualifier"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</td>
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the help! Do you know how to go about the same request, but with Mirage theme instead of Mirage2? my institution is evaluating which theme to use

Comment: For the Mirage theme, here are the lines to look for (it's the same with Mirage2, only the line numbers are different): [item-view.xsl](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/lib/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl#L341-L349)

Comment: Amazing. The part of the code that I copied from your comment is working perfectly, I added a couple more that ended up looking like this (for example):
xmlui.dri2xhtml.METS-1.0.item-mimetype
I guess I have to change a messages.xml file. Do you know if its the main one, or if there is an specific file for the item-view.xsl messages?

Comment: The "live" `messages.xml` can be found in `[dspace]/webapps/xmlui/i18n` but I suggest that to avoid over writing this file after rebuild, copy this file to `[dspace-source]/dspace/modules/xmlui/src/main/webapp/i18n`.